# exporting geodeg.com data

Tags: wikimapia

Looking at a fairly old answer regarding exporting wikimapia data, there was a recommendation to use geodeg.com - it is indeed an easy interface. However, there doesn't seem to be an option of exporting en mass all the data but only the option to select 50 at a time.

Is there an option to export to KML or similar type all the information?

For example, all the schools in Albania - http://geodeg.com/search.php?q=school&language=&country=2

Comment: Can you include a link to that answer in your question, please?